# Группировка по двумя полям и COUNT

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `status` 
(
  `hosts` text,
  `numb` text,
  `region` text,
  `status` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `t_tim` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)
ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AVG_ROW_LENGTH=34;

INSERT INTO `status` (`hosts`, `numb`, `region`, `status`, `t_tim`) VALUES
('SIU02', '234', 'POV', '1', '2017-01-18 03:44:01'),
('SIU04', '44', 'POV', '1', '2017-01-18 03:44:01'),
('SIU03', '24234', 'POV', '1', '2017-01-18 03:44:01'),
('SIU01', '24234', 'POV', '1', '2017-01-18 03:44:01'),
('SIU02', '24234', 'SZ', '1', '2017-01-18 03:44:01'),
('SIU01', '22', 'SIB', '1', '2017-01-18 03:44:01'),
('SIU02', '34', 'SIB', '1', '2017-01-18 03:44:01'),
('SIU03', '422', 'SIB', '1', '2017-01-18 03:44:01'),
('SIU04', '23456', 'SIB', '1', '2017-01-18 03:44:01'),
('SIU05', '46', 'SIB', '1', '2017-01-18 03:44:01'),
('SIU07', '324234', 'SIB', '2', '2017-01-18 08:45:12'),
('SU_FTP', '324', 'MSK', '0', '2017-01-18 03:44:01'),
('SIU01', '34234', 'SZ', '1', '2017-01-18 03:44:01'),
('SIU08', '23443', 'SIB', '1', '2017-01-18 03:44:01'),
('SIU04', '3444', 'SZ', '1', '2017-01-18 03:44:01'),
('SIU03', '1555', 'SZ', '1', '2017-01-18 03:44:01'),
('SIU05', '1055', 'SZ', '1', '2017-01-18 03:44:01'),
('S_FTP', '1223', 'SZ', '1', '2017-01-18 03:44:01'),
('SIU01', '1232333', 'UG', '2', '2017-01-18 08:45:20'),
('SIU02', '134234', 'UG', '1', '2017-01-18 03:44:01'),
('SIU03', '155', 'UG', '1', '2017-01-18 03:44:01'),
('SIU04', '14545', 'UG', '1', '2017-01-18 03:44:01'),
('S_FTP', '1454', 'UG', '2', '2017-01-18 08:45:23'),
('S_FTP', '14545', 'POV', '2', '2017-01-18 08:45:06');
```

Как построить выборку, чтобы выводилась сумма значений `status` по каждому `region`? Для `status=1`, `status=2`, `status=3`, `status=0` с группировкой по `region`.

Не могу составить выборку, т.к. не знаю что делать, если для `region` не будет, например, значения `status=2`.

В итоге должно быть, например:

```
region--status--count
POV----1--------4
```

Comment: Т.е. вам _нужны_ записи с 0 в случае если какого то статуса для региона нет ?

Comment: Называть одинаково таблицу и поле в ней - решение, на мой взгляд, неудачное.

Comment: Если такого статуса нет - его можно просто не выводить или заполнить каким-то значением по умолчанию, например 999

Comment: Ну не выводить и "по умолчанию" это две большие разницы. в первом случае у вас просто `select region, status, count(1) from tab group by region, status`, а во втором случае гораздо сложнее и главное, гораздо медленее работать будет

Comment: Не выводить. Конструкцию Case можно не использовать для заполнения по умолчанию.

Comment: @DimaKuzmin добавьте в вопросе полный желаемый вывод для представленных вами данных. Это снимет многие вопросы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT region,status, COUNT(*)
FROM `status`
WHERE status IN (0, 1, 2, 3)
GROUP BY region, status
```

Comment: точно, не подумал, спасибо

Comment: добавил, сейчас все как надо. просто в вашем вопросе написано "группировкой по region"

Comment: Вопрос не мой. То что формулировка вопроса крайне мутная - спору нет.

Comment: Если мой ответ помог, защитайте мне его. спасибо

Comment: @L.Vadim [Ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/616255/220571) был дан раннее? Если да, то нет оснований, чтобы ваш ответ отмечать как принямый.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov Просто в вопросе, не было поставленно задачи про group by status, я его изменил по комментарию, который удалили. все правельно

Answer (score 3):

Спасибо за помощь!

```
SELECT
  region,
  status,
  COUNT(*)
FROM `status`
WHERE status IN (0, 1, 2, 3)
GROUP BY region,status
```

Comment: А чем ваш ответ отличается от ответа L.Vadim?

Comment: Пожалуйста, не отвечайте фразой «спасибо». Вместо этого, **[отметьте лучший ответ как принятый](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)** (галка напротив выбранного ответа). - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/136193)

Comment: @Denis тем, что был дан раньше, чем L.Vadim исправил ошибку в своём ответе. Комментарии свои под его ответом я уже удалил, но сводилось всё к тому, что я дважды писал, что `status` нужно добавить в `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT `status`.`region`, `status`.`status`, COUNT(*)
FROM `status`
GROUP BY `status`.`region`, `status`.`status`;
```